# Issue: Outlook Event meeting Invitation's title display Email subject instead of Event title

Tags: node.js, outlook, icalendar, nodemailer, outlook-calendar

I'm learning how to use Nodemailer to send an Email to an Outlook account, and already sent some mail successfully. And also  sucessfully sent an attachment of an Outlook Event invitation using .ics file.

But then I realized an Invitation attached in my Email has a Title using the Email Subject instead of SUMMARY field in .ics file below:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:Calendar
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Japan
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19390101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0900
TZOFFSETTO:+0900
TZNAME:JST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:Mailto:toransu_home@exmaple.com
UID:00112015050@exmaple.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:This is an event description. 
DTSTAMP;TZID=Japan:20191216T152657
DTSTART;TZID=Japan:20191226
DTEND;TZID=Japan:20191228
LOCATION:[MiềnNam]HCM
SUMMARY: This is an event Title
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I've read that in .ics file, SUMMARY field is Event's title. But I don't know why Calendar event's title display as Email's subject instead of event's title(SUMMARY). However, if I leave Email subject empty, event's title will display normally (using SUMMARY field in .ics file.)

Anyone know why ? Or is it suppose to be like that with Outlook?

Thank you very much!